# Empty Tile title in a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app with WMS

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How do use set an empty title for a tile in a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app with WMS?

Without WMS, I could just set the `DisplayName` to empty string in `WMAppManifest.xml` and it worked. With WMS, I can no longer set `DisplayName` to an empty string in `Package.appxmanifest` so the app title is always shown on the medium tile and I do not want to shown there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it's not the same.  By default you'll have the app title displayed.  But when you update the tile with TileUpdateManager you can remove the title.  Check the "branding" attribute set to "none"

```
var tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWidePeekImageAndText01);                
var tileImageAttributes = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
((XmlElement)tileImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appdata:///local" + wideBackGroundUri.LocalPath);
var brandingAttribute = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("binding");
((XmlElement)brandingAttribute[0]).SetAttribute("branding", "none");
tileXml.SelectSingleNode("//text[@id=1]").InnerText = wideBackContent;
TileNotification tileNotification = new TileNotification(tileXml);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileNotification);
```

Just before the `new TileNotification` you can add the following code.

```
  var squareTileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquarePeekImageAndText04);
            var squareTileXmlAttributes = squareTileXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
            ((XmlElement)squareTileXmlAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appdata:///local" + backGroundUri.LocalPath);

            var brandingSquareAttribute = squareTileXml.GetElementsByTagName("binding");
            ((XmlElement)brandingSquareAttribute[0]).SetAttribute("branding", "none");

            squareTileXml.SelectSingleNode("//text[@id=1]").InnerText = backContent;

            IXmlNode node = tileXml.ImportNode(squareTileXml.GetElementsByTagName("binding").Item(0), true);
            tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("visual").Item(0).AppendChild(node);
```

Comment: Works for wide tile, but what about the medium tile (TileSquare71x71Image)? There is no TileSquare71x71Image with a title definition

Comment: Yes because I need that but you can find another template here http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tiletemplatetype